# Magento 2 I want to get order increment id and update all item of sales_order_item table order wise in below observer. How can i do that

Tags: magento2, database, event-observer

I want to get order increment id and update all item of sales_order_item table order wise in below observer. How can i do that

```
    namespace Namespace\Moduename\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 

class OrderSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface { 

    protected $connector; 
    protected $_itemFactory; 
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item $itemFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) { 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
        $this->_itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {  
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();


    }

}
```

Comment: when you want to do this?

Comment: when "sales_order_save_after" observer event is fire.